# Create a project (text file encoding) to use UTF-16 on linux

Tags: linux, unicode, porting

I am doing a job porting a Windows project to Linux, encoding UTF-16, but Linux's default encoding is UTF-8.

> g++ test.cpp ;
>     occurred error: warning: null character(s) ignored.
>   locate –a ;
>     no UTF-16 character set.

1. Can I compile utf-16 from Linux (Ubuntu11.04)?
2. How to do insert UTF-16 characters in Linux?

Comment: Either convert your source to UTF-8 with `iconv` or pass `-finput-charset=UTF-16` to g++.

Comment: UTF-16 is the encoding of what? Source files? Data files?

Comment: @Rakkun:thank you,g++ -finput-charset=UTF-16 test.cpp,error: failure to convert UTF-16 to UTF-8

Comment: @n.m. Encoding 'UTF-16' Source files

Comment: Eclipse:Create c++ project, change Text file Encoding:”UTF-8” to ”UTF-16”, and new a test.cpp.But build fault

Comment: The only way to work with such files is to convert them to UTF-8 with `iconv`. `-finput-charset=UTF-16` will only work if your files do not use any system includes, which no non-trivial programs do.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your source files to UTF-8. Either use a good text editor or iconv. It will make your life much easier... Linux's header files are UTF-8 system-wide. Insisting on UTF-16 is like pulling teeth with tweezers, sans anesthetic.

Comment: My old project is windows Platform for vs2010 Develop,now it porting to linux for Cross-platform by eclipse ,must source file to utf-16,it is big project. Use iconv character set file conversion is too slow, the impact speed of development

Comment: Can GCC/G++ compile the file in utf-16 under ?

Comment: Especially if it is a big project you will HAVE TO convert to UTF-8. Period.